# Less obvious "The table 'mytable' is full" error

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, configuration, redhat

Error in mysqld.log:

```
2020-02-02T01:17:32.133974Z 3069 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: The table 'IS_DUT_IFID' is full
```

None of the many threads I've found about this error have helped me to resolve this issue.

Here's what I've checked or tried so far:

- *innodb_data_file_path* - **autoextend**
- *innodb_temp_data_file_path* - **autoextend**
- *innodb_file_per_table* - **ON** (and in effect)
- */var/lib/mysql* and */tmp* disk space - **47GB available**
- *innodb_buffer_pool_** increased

  - 1 instance of 128 MB (default) increased to **4 instances of 256MB** for a total of 1GB
- no extra large blobs being used to my knowledge but did this just in case as it was the only other suggestion I could find:

  - *innodb_log_file_size* increased from 50MB (default) to 128 MB
  - *innodb_log_buffer_size* increased from 16MB (default) to 32 MB

I did notice IS_DUT_IFID.ibd recently passed the 4GB mark.  The file is on an ext4 volume managed by Red Hat 6.8.  It is 32-bit, but the file being over 4GB doesn't appear to be causing the OS any problems and shouldn't be hitting any OS limits according to this: https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-limits

Server has 8GB RAM, but I guess only 4GB would be available to any given process due to it being 32-bit.  I was under the impression MySQL could intelligently process chunks at a time and would only load what it needed to so this shouldn't be an issue.  Maybe I'm wrong?

My only thought is to upgrade the OS to 64-bit so I can run MySQL 64-bit, but I'd much prefer to leave this server as is if at all possible.  Any advice greatly appreciated!

.

### MySQL info:

```
mysql> show table status like 'IS_DUT_IFID';
+-------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name        | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows     | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+-------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| IS_DUT_IFID | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 35362861 |             32 |  1160773632 |               0 |   2279604224 |   6291456 |           NULL | 2020-01-30 15:11:10 | 2020-02-02 11:00:38 | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+-------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%innodb%';
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value                  |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| ignore_builtin_innodb                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                 | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm             | 10                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index               | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts         | 8                      |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay          | 150000                 |
| innodb_api_bk_commit_interval            | 5                      |
| innodb_api_disable_rowlock               | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_mdl                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_trx_level                     | 0                      |
| innodb_autoextend_increment              | 64                     |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                 | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size            | 268435456              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown      | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now              | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct              | 25                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename              | ib_buffer_pool         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances             | 4                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort            | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup       | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now              | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                  | 1073741824             |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size            | 25                     |
| innodb_change_buffering                  | all                    |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm                | crc32                  |
| innodb_checksums                         | ON                     |
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled             | OFF                    |
| innodb_commit_concurrency                | 0                      |
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct | 5                      |
| innodb_compression_level                 | 6                      |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max           | 50                     |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets               | 5000                   |
| innodb_data_file_path                    | ibdata1:12M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                     |                        |
| innodb_deadlock_detect                   | ON                     |
| innodb_default_row_format                | dynamic                |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache           | OFF                    |
| innodb_doublewrite                       | ON                     |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                     | 1                      |
| innodb_file_format                       | Barracuda              |
| innodb_file_format_check                 | ON                     |
| innodb_file_format_max                   | Barracuda              |
| innodb_file_per_table                    | ON                     |
| innodb_fill_factor                       | 100                    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout              | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit           | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                      |                        |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                   | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_sync                        | ON                     |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                | 30                     |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted              | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery                    | 0                      |
| innodb_ft_aux_table                      |                        |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                     | 8000000                |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print              | OFF                    |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                | ON                     |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                 | 84                     |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                 | 3                      |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize              | 2000                   |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit             | 2000000000             |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table          |                        |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                | 2                      |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size               | 640000000              |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table            |                        |
| innodb_io_capacity                       | 200                    |
| innodb_io_capacity_max                   | 2000                   |
| innodb_large_prefix                      | ON                     |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                 | 50                     |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog           | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                   | 33554432               |
| innodb_log_checksums                     | ON                     |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages              | ON                     |
| innodb_log_file_size                     | 134217728              |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                | ./                     |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size              | 8192                   |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth                    | 1024                   |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct               | 75.000000              |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm           | 0.000000               |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                     | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay               | 0                      |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                 | 1073741824             |
| innodb_monitor_disable                   |                        |
| innodb_monitor_enable                    |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset                     |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all                 |                        |
| innodb_numa_interleave                   | OFF                    |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                    | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                   | 1000                   |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size         | 134217728              |
| innodb_open_files                        | 2000                   |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only            | OFF                    |
| innodb_page_cleaners                     | 4                      |
| innodb_page_size                         | 16384                  |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                  | 300                    |
| innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency     | 128                    |
| innodb_purge_threads                     | 4                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold              | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                   | 4                      |
| innodb_read_only                         | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                 | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout               | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                 | 128                    |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                  | 1048576                |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                   | 6                      |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                 | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_include_delete_marked       | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_method                      | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_persistent                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages     | 20                     |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages                | 8                      |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages      | 8                      |
| innodb_status_output                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_status_output_locks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_strict_mode                       | ON                     |
| innodb_support_xa                        | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_array_size                   | 1                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                   | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                       | ON                     |
| innodb_temp_data_file_path               | ibtmp1:12M:autoextend  |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                | 0                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                | 10000                  |
| innodb_tmpdir                            |                        |
| innodb_undo_directory                    | ./                     |
| innodb_undo_log_truncate                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_undo_logs                         | 128                    |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces                  | 0                      |
| innodb_use_native_aio                    | ON                     |
| innodb_version                           | 5.7.29                 |
| innodb_write_io_threads                  | 4                      |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
134 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%tmp%';
+----------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                    | Value    |
+----------------------------------+----------+
| default_tmp_storage_engine       | InnoDB   |
| innodb_tmpdir                    |          |
| internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine | InnoDB   |
| max_tmp_tables                   | 32       |
| slave_load_tmpdir                | /tmp     |
| tmp_table_size                   | 16777216 |
| tmpdir                           | /tmp     |
+----------------------------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%datadir%';
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| datadir       | /var/lib/mysql/ |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.29    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Additional info:

Originating INSERT error from Perl script:

```
The table 'IS_DUT_IFID' is full [for Statement "INSERT INTO IS_DUT_IFID ( ddv_id, dut_ifid_id, is_id) VALUES ( '84600', 3172, 1594897 )"]
```

Comment: If the OS is 32-bit, it cannot use your 8GB of RAM!  Only half of that!

Comment: @RickJames Depends on what you mean by "it", I suppose.  The OS can use more with PAE.  I think the MySQL server process would be limited to 4GB.  I limited the buffer pool allocation and memory usage didn't appear to be growing anywhere near 4GB, but it's possible that was somehow related so that's why I moved to 64 bit.

Comment: A 32-bit OS cannot touch anything address above 4 billion.  Nor can any program running on that server.  The CPU simply has no physical way to do it.  The other 4GB is sitting there collecting dust.  If you have 64-bit OS, but 32-bit MySQL, then MySQL cannot, for example, use a buffer_pool > 4G.  The OS can see all 8GB, but MySQL cannot see more than 4GB.

Comment: OK, I'm reading about PAE....

Comment: OK, I guess I snoozed through the invention of PAE.  But it still sounds like MySQL must be 64-bit in order to access more than 4GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like the answer: Upgrade the OS to 64-bit to run the 64-bit version of MySQL.

Interestingly, there is a limit to the size of an InnoDB table in Windows 32

Note Bulletpoint 10 of [MySQL Documentation on "InnoDB Limits"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-limits.html)

> Tablespace files cannot exceed 4GB on Windows 32-bit systems ([Bug #80149](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80149)).

Note the excerpt from that bug report (submitted 2020-01-26 08:10 AM)

> When the temporary table reaches 4GB in size, the testcase fails like
>   this:
>
> mysql> insert into t select * from t; Query OK, 98304 rows affected (6
>   min 54.49 sec) Records: 98304  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
>
> mysql> insert into t select * from t; ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table
>   'c:\tmp#sql2cc04_17_10' is full
>
> o) Works on Linux 64-bit and Windows 64-bit works okay. o) tmpdir and
>   datadir has plenty of free space.

That looks like your situation as well.

Perhaps the same limit exists for the 32-bit version of MySQL as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... and all of the other replies you've made over the years.  I've learned a lot from your posts!

Comment: It's taking some time to migrate to the 64-bit OS and it'll take more time to test the changes.  Hopefully I'll be able to post a successful update next week.

Comment: You should bump up innodb_buffer_pool_size to 6G. You can run `SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 6;`. Then, add `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G` to `my.cnf`.

Comment: Migrating to 64-bit MySQL did indeed resolve the issue.  Now that that issue is resolved, I can look into upping the buffer pool size.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Table is full" almost always indicates a disk space issue.  It could be in your main disk partition or in the "tmp" partition.

The buffer_pool does cache stuff.  You have `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G`.  So, regardless of 32-bit vs 64-bit, and regardless of the size of the table, that size will work -- maybe slower for a bigger table, but it will still work.  (1G would be too big if your available RAM were under 2GB.  But, again, you would not see "table is full".)

> /var/lib/mysql and /tmp disk space - 47GB available

In both?  Or in each?  InnoDB is smart enough to have a table span two disk partitions.  So, how much is available in each?

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%dir%';
```